# oop php new class User extends DB

Tags: php, class

I am new to oop php and copied source from somewhere, modify and test them. No idea what's wrong to new a User class.

```
class DB {

    private $dbHost     = "127.0.0.1";
    private $dbUsername = "root";
    private $dbPassword = "";
    private $dbName     = "hihi";

    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($this->db)){
            // Connect to the database
            try{
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbHost.";dbname=".$this->dbName.";charset=utf8",  $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
                $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                $this->db = $conn;

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL: " . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $this->db = null;   
    }

    public function display($sql){
        ..............
        return html_table;
    }

    public function insert($sql){
        ..............

    }
}
```

index.php // it doesn't work

```
include 'DB.php';
include 'User.php';

$users = new User();
$users -> getAllUsers();
```

User.php // it doesn't work

```
class User extends DB{
    public function getAllUsers(){      
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userview WHERE event = 'a' ORDER BY created DESC";
    $users = $this->db->display($sql);
    echo $users;                
    }
}
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::display() in C:\Program Files (x86)...

If I change User.php to below,

User.php // it doesn't work

```
class User extends DB{
    public function getAllUsers(){      
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userview WHERE event = 'a' ORDER BY created DESC";
    $users = $this->display($sql);
    echo $users;                
    }
}
```

Fatal error: User Object ( [dbHost:DB:private] => 127.0.0.1 [dbUsername:DB:private] => root [dbPassword:DB:private] => [dbName:DB:private] => hihi [db] => PDO Object ( ) )

User.php // it doesn't work

```
class User extends DB{
    public function getAllUsers(){      
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userview WHERE event = 'a' ORDER BY created DESC";
    $users = display($sql);
    echo $users;                
    }
}
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined function display() in C:\Program Files (x86)...

If I don't create a user class, it works.

index.php // it works

```
include 'DB.php';
$db = new DB();

$users = $db->display("SELECT * FROM userview WHERE event = 'a' ORDER BY created DESC");
echo $users;
```

I want to create class User, Company,....to extends DB in order to use DB's class method for select, update, delete...but Fatal error occurs. Pls. help. Many thanks.

Comment: You should add your User class definition.

Comment: The fatal error you mentioned has an 'F' at the end of the method call. Is that a typo 'displayF()' vs 'display()'

Comment: Stop making database wrapper classes and learn how to use prepared statements. Also, FYI, "User" is not a special subtype of "Database".

Comment: Hi terešk, so should I include function display, update in class User, Company...? If so, the function will be similar and repetitive.

Comment: "User" is not a special subtype of "Database". Yes I agree. But in real situtaion, almost all the data are drawn from a db. BTW, 1. user and company are m to 1 situation, 2. there are no subclass of user and company. Any suggestion for that? Thanks.